# Megacool SDK, referral system, receivedShareOpened and sentShareOpened never gets called

Tags: android

I'm trying [Megacool](https://megacool.medal.tv/) for the first time.
I did everything (as far as I know) as the documentation suggested.

**So far I can do the following:**

1. Device A launches app, shares referral link.
2. Device B can install the app through the referral link
3. I know that URL schemes are working becaue if the app is pre-installed it pops me the option to open the link with the app itself.

However, the main point is missing, the 2 function which should handle the reward/gift after the referral never gets called on neither of the devices.

**This code just never gets fired in my MainActivity:**

```
Megacool.start(this, getString(R.string.megacool_api_key), new MegacoolConfig()
            .eventListener(new co.megacool.megacool.EventListener() {
                @Override
                public void receivedShareOpened(@NonNull ReceivedShareOpenedEvent event) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Got event: " + event);
                    if (event.isFirstSession()) {
                        // This device has received a share and installed the
                        // app for the first time
                        Log.d(TAG, "Installed from a referral from " + event.getSenderUserId());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Installed from a referral from " + event.getSenderUserId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       }
                }

                @Override
                public void sentShareOpened(@NonNull SentShareOpenedEvent event) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got event: " + event);
                    if (event.isFirstSession()) {
                        // A share sent from this device has been opened, and
                        // the receiver installed the app for the first time
                        Log.d(TAG, event.getReceiverUserId() + " installed the app from our referral");

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, event.getReceiverUserId() + " installed the app from our referral", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            })
    );
```

The strange thinig is that **I actually see the invitations analytics** in the Megacool dashboard:

[image]

I also tried Megacool's troubleshooting and tried debug functions like:

```
 Megacool.getInstance().resetIdentity();
```

Which would resets the app's identity so it would ALWAYS get the referral as a "new" one but no success.

I also tried to simulate the referral linking [through adb according to Megacool's doc.](https://docs.megacool.co/learn/testing/android?language=java&app=duelsrpg-cc)

And I also tried with internal testing from the Google Play Store, **so with actual app installs.**

Please, help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the Megacool devs.

I took a look at the data we have for your app, according to our backend the events were delivered to both devices. There's only one event that had `isFirstSession` set to true though, so most of them would only have logged the event, not shown the toast.

Couple things to check:

1. Did you call `resetIdentity()` *before* calling `start()`? This is crucial for the referral testing for the events to be registered with `isFirstSession`.
2. If you're not seeing the debug logging from the events, do you see other logs with the same verbosity level (debug)? A lot of Android devices hide anything below info or warning.
3. Where are you initializing the SDK? It should be done as soon as possible in the Activity lifecycle, `onCreate` is usually the best bet (`onCreate` for the Application is also an option). This ensures that the event listeners are registered before any events are fired by the OS.
4. You can turn on debug output by calling `Megacool.setDebug(true)`, this makes the SDK much more verbose and might help you catch what's happening from logs.

If none of this works feel free to reach out on Intercom and I can take a look at your apk or help you grok the debug logs to figure out what's going on.